# How to create a pandas dataframe with 2 dataframes one as columns and one as rows

Tags: python, pandas, join, merge

I have a 2 dataframes as follow:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Barcode':[1,2,3,4],'Store':['s1','s2','s3','s4']})    

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Date':['2020-10-10','2020-10-09','2020-10-08','2020-10-07','2020-10-06']})
```

How to have a dataframe which has df1 as rows and df2 as columns and consequently generate cells with null values.Something like below:

[image]

And the final step is to fill the cells with join on another table(df4):

```
df4 = pd.DataFrame({'Barcode':[1,2,3,4],'Store':['s1','s2','s3','s4'],'2020-10-10':[1,2,5,np.nan],'2020-10-09':[np.nan,2,3,0],'2020-10-08':[0,0,2,3],'2020-10-07':[np.nan,1,np.nan,2]})
```

Final df should look like bellow:

[image]

Any help is truly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First create a temporary DataFrame:

```
wrk = pd.DataFrame('', index=pd.MultiIndex.from_frame(df1),
    columns=df2.Date.rename(None)); wrk
```

It is filled with empty strings, and has required column names from
*df2*. For now *Barcode* and *Store* are **index** columns.
This arrangement will be needed soon.

Then update it (in-place) with the data from *df4*:

```
wrk.update(df4.set_index(['Barcode', 'Store']))
```

And the last step is:

```
result = wrk.reset_index()
```

The result is:

```
   Barcode Store 2020-10-10 2020-10-09 2020-10-08 2020-10-07 2020-10-06
0        1    s1          1                     0                      
1        2    s2          2          2          0          1           
2        3    s3          5          3          2                      
3        4    s4                     0          3          2
```

Answer (score 3):

I hope I've understood your question right. You have 3 dataframes:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Barcode':[1,2,3,4],'Store':['s1','s2','s3','s4']})    
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Date':['2020-10-10','2020-10-09','2020-10-08','2020-10-07','2020-10-06']})
df4 = pd.DataFrame({'Barcode':[1,2,3,4],'Store':['s1','s2','s3','s4'],'2020-10-10':[1,2,5,np.nan],'2020-10-09':[np.nan,2,3,0],'2020-10-08':[0,0,2,3],'2020-10-07':[np.nan,1,np.nan,2]})
```

---

Then:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(df1, columns= df1.columns.tolist() + df2['Date'].tolist())
df1 = df1.set_index('Barcode')
df4 = df4.set_index('Barcode')

print(df1.fillna(df4))
```

Prints:

```
        Store  2020-10-10  2020-10-09  2020-10-08  2020-10-07  2020-10-06
Barcode                                                                  
1          s1         1.0         NaN         0.0         NaN         NaN
2          s2         2.0         2.0         0.0         1.0         NaN
3          s3         5.0         3.0         2.0         NaN         NaN
4          s4         NaN         0.0         3.0         2.0         NaN
```

Answer (score 2):

```
for item in df2.Date.tolist():
    df1[item] = np.nan

dfinal = df1.fillna(df4)
dfinal = dfinal.set_index('Barcode')
display(dfinal)
```